# How to use output from expand.grid in foreach loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, foreach, parallel-processing, iteration

I want to create different training data using SMOTE in R by varying the K and dup_size value. To do that, first I should generate combinations of K and dup_size. Next using each combination I have to create a training dataset.
I have K values and dup_size as follows

```
K = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
dup_size = c(10, 20, 30, 35, 40)
```

Inorder to find combinations, I used `expand.grid` from the base functions.

```
combinations = expand.grid(K = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
                          dup_size = c(10, 20, 30, 35, 40))
```

Now, I have a dataframe of 25 combinations as follows.

```
> dput(combinations)
structure(list(K = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), dup_size = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 40)), out.attrs = list(dim = c(K = 5L, dup_size = 5L
), dimnames = list(K = c("K=1", "K=2", "K=3", "K=4", "K=5"), 
    dup_size = c("dup_size=10", "dup_size=20", "dup_size=30", 
    "dup_size=35", "dup_size=40"))), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-25L))
```

As a next step, I want to iterate through these 25 rows of combination one by one and at each step, I want the function to pick up K and dup_size from these rows.

I used a foreach loop to do this.

```
library(parallel)
library(iterators)
detectCores()

cl = parallel::makeCluster(detectCores())
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
on.exit(parallel::stopCluster(cl))

smoteResult = foreach(
  iterParams = iter(combinations, "row"),
  .packages = c("dplyr", "smotefamily")
) %dopar% {
  samplingData = smotefamily::SMOTE(featureData, labelData, iterParams) %>%
    .$data
}
```

For some reason, this isn't working. I'm getting an error like this.

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "invalid 'length' argument"
```

I want to store the output at each step to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
library(parallel)
library(iterators)
detectCores()

cl = parallel::makeCluster(detectCores())
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
on.exit(parallel::stopCluster(cl))

smoteResult = foreach(
  iterParams = iter(combinations, "row"),
  .packages = c("dplyr", "smotefamily")
) %dopar% {
  samplingData = do.call(
     smotefamily::SMOTE, c(list(featureData, labelData), as.data.frame(iterParams))) %>%
    .$data
}
```

PD: Note that I do not see the variables featureData, labelData in your example to test it.

Comment: I want to add these combinations as a new column for each iteration. For example when K = 1 and dup_size = 10, I want to add a new column names K and populate it with value 1 and a new column named dup_size and populate it with 10. Likewise I want to do this operation in each iteration.

Comment: Not sure if samplingData is a dataframe. If it is the case, add these lines to the %dopar% block :  `samplingData$K <- iterParams[,"K"];   samplingData$dup_size <- iterParams[,"dup_size"]; return(samplingData)`